# Is it true that having speed camera alerter is illegal in France?

Tags: france

I have heard stories of people that drive around Europe, that particularly in France you can get fined for using any Navigation system or device that comes bundled with, fixed Speed camera alerts.

Is this true? And do any other countries in the world do the same thing.

I know that you MUST have a single use breathalyser in your car at all times in France.

Comment: I think it's a travel question, I don't see how is this expat related

Answer (score 6):

They are forbidden in France. [This table](http://www.eu-verbraucher.de/fileadmin/user_upload/eu-verbraucher/PDF/Sonstige_pdfs/Kopie_von_tabel_Radar_Detection_rules_ECCNet__2_.pdf) made by the German consumer council is listing up all European countries in this respect.

The green column is indicating where GPS alerting is allowed and the orange one where Radar-alerter are allowed. The violet one indicates the fine in case you are caught.

[Here is a google translation of the PDF](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.eu-verbraucher.de/fileadmin/user_upload/eu-verbraucher/PDF/Sonstige_pdfs/Kopie_von_tabel_Radar_Detection_rules_ECCNet__2_.pdf).

Comment: Radar detector allowed in UK :) Fantastic !

Comment: I wonder what they can do about Waze.

Comment: @Karlson they can simply block any connections to Waze's server if they want to

Comment: @MeNoTalk The Great French Firewall?

Comment: @Karlson you mean "Le grand pare-feu français", thanks to google translate ;)

Comment: I wonder if the French law says any kind of information about speed camera, or bundled static data only. This waze looks really interesting :)

Comment: I don't really see what's specific about Waze.

Comment: I think using Waze is similar to listening to a radio which sometimes broadcasts user messages about speed camera sightings.